# No limit to file generation?

Tags: python

Is there no limit as to how many files can be created in a code in python, like there is a recursion limit? I have this bit of code here,

```
each = 0
while True:
    with open('filenamewhtever'+str(each)+'.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(str(each))
    each += 1
```

which seems to work just fine, although it quickly filled a lot of memory in the folder. Could this,if unchecked, potentially have crashed  my pc? Also, shouldnt the compiler have a failsafe switch to prevent this?

Comment: Why would a *compiler* have a failsafe on what you can do long after your code has been compiled? The compiler can only verify syntax; it can't stop you from doing foolish things in your code. Compilers are only checking to make sure that your code is syntactically correct - they cannot check to make sure you have no logic errors in your code. That's the programmer's job. Also, folders don't use *memory*. Contents of a folder are files or folders, which use *disk space*. There's a significant difference between them.

Answer (score 2):

There is typically an operating system defined limit to how many files you can have *open* at the same time. But because the `with` statement closes each file after you've written it, you don't run into this limit.

There might also be limits imposed by the file system on how many files can be in a single directory. You might see certain operations (like listing the files) become slow, well before you even come close to that limit.

And finally, you are obviously limited by disk space.

Comment: To piggy back on this, the open-file limit is an OS-level feature, and not something that Python is very conscious of. When the OS determines you've opened enough files, it won't give you a handle when the low-level Python/C code asks the shell for one.

Comment: It doesn't ask the shell, but rather the kernel (typically via libc).